# Error : Cannot Access ppa while installing openstack swift

Tags: apt, virtualbox, ppa

I was trying to install openstack swift all in one. Getting the error as follows:

```
root@openstack-VirtualBox:/home/openstack# apt-add-repository ppa:swift-core/ppa
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~swift-core/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Whether I use `apt-add` or `add-apt`.. Error remains the same.

```
root@openstack-VirtualBox:/home/openstack# add-apt-repository ppa:swift-core/ppa
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~swift-core/+archive/ppa) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Please let me know the issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

The right PPA entry is  `ppa:swift-core/release`

Open The Ubuntu Software Centre and ‘mouse’ over the top panel to reveal the Application Menu.

It’s here you paste/type the ‘PPA’ address.

```
ppa:swift-core/release
```

[image]

Comment: Have added the ppa:swift-core/ppa in software sources using the add option. But the issue still exists.

Comment: My Internet is working as well.

Comment: Your entry should be ppa:swift-core/release, not ppa:swift-core/ppa.

Answer (score 0):

@Ashwini

If you are installing OpenStack packages from 12.04 version onwards please use Ubuntu Cloud Archive

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive

You can easily decide on which version of OpenStack you want to install.